# Transform Error in react native when using downloaded (PNG) images

Tags: image, reactjs, react-native, frontend, transformation

I get error when i write

```
                <Image
                    resizeMode="contain"
                    resizeMethod='scale'
                    style={{ borderRadius: 15, flex: 1 }}
                    source={require('@assets/pdf-icon (1).png')}
                />
```

I guess the Image isn't getting transformed properly by react native
Here's a screenshot of the error i received!
[image]

I used a png image :
[image]

Comment: I am also facing the same issue, were you able to solve it?